# Is it possible to access SQL Server Service Broker from a C# app?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005, service-broker

I want to use the SQL Server Service Broker to generate a message (inside SQL Server) and for it to be read in an external C# app.

I am limited to Windows 2003 running SQL Server 2005. I've read a bunch of articles, that allude to this being a possibility, but I do not see an example anywhere. Is this possible?

Comment: Sorry for no constructive idea about the question, just wanted to point out that SQL Server 2005 doesn't even have extended support in a year so coding something new on it may be something to reconsider.

Comment: Is executing a sproc an option?

Comment: @JeffO Yes, I can execute a sproc, but the point of the exercise is not to poll the database for events, but rather to receive them in the C# app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

T-SQL has statements for accessing Service Broker: SEND, RECEIVE and others. You can use ADO.NET to execute them.

Comment: What does SSMS have to do with the service broker?  Am I missing something?

Comment: @AngryHacker, I think my answer is not very clear. Let me ask a question: Why can't your C# app read events by executing a RECEIVE statement?

Comment: @AngryHacker: Service Broker is entirely contained within SQL Server. You use T-SQL ([`SEND`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188407.aspx), [`RECEIVE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186963.aspx)) and you exchange messages from a SQL Server instance to another SQL Server instance. You cannot send messages to a C# application, but you *can* send messages to a queue (hosted in SQL Server) from which the C# application reads the message(s).

Comment: @usr It can.  I just didn't know that such a statement existed 24 hours ago.  Thanks.